# What's concise/idiomatic way to get row-wise equality of 2d arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

With 2 numpy 2-d arrays, I'd like a result array filled with row-by-row equality results. For example:

```py
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
>>> b = np.array([[5, 6], [3, 4], [1, 2]])
>>> a == b  # not quite what I want
array([[False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False]])
>>> np.equal(a, b)  # also not quite
array([[False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False]])
```

The result I want, each row's equality as one element, would be:

```py
array([False,  True, False])
```

What's the compact/idiomatic way to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all()` over `axis=1` to turn each row of `[bool, ...]` into `True` if all-true, and `False` if any false.

For example:

```py
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
>>> b = np.array([[5, 6], [3, 4], [1, 2]])
>>> np.all(a == b, axis=1)
array([False,  True, False])
```